# Basic Error while web scraping using Selenium and Edge with Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-chromium

Code trials:

```
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
errors = []
season = []
```

The code runs fine till loading.
An error pops in when I write the following code:

```
for id in range(46605, 46985):
my_url = f'https://www.premierleague.com/match/{id}'
option = Options()
option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=option)
driver.get(my_url)
```

The following error pops up:

[image: Error Screenshot 1]

Error Screenshot 2:

[image: Error Screenshot 2]

Comment: Posting code/errors as images makes it harder for us to help.  Please edit the question, and include all code and error messages as plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the *Chromium* based [edge](/questions/tagged/edge) with [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) ***v4.x*** you have to install the following packages:

- *msedge-selenium-tools*:

  ```
  pip install msedge-selenium-tools
  ```
- Code Block :

  ```
  from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge

  s = Service('/path/to/edge')
  driver = Edge(service=s)
  ```

---

To use the *Chromium* based [edge](/questions/tagged/edge) with in [headless](/questions/tagged/headless) mode you need the `EdgeOptions` class.

- Code Block :

  ```
  from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
  from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge

  # make Edge headless
  edge_options = EdgeOptions()
  edge_options.use_chromium = True  # required to make Edge headless
  s = Service('/path/to/edge')
  driver = Edge(service=s, options=edge_options)
  ```

Comment: Can you help me further? I have shifted to a chrome instead of edge and this particular code block ran fine but there's a new webdriver issue I am facing.

Comment: @KaustavMallick Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. So contributor will be happy to help you out.